# Server managed roster in Tigase

Tags: xmpp, tigase

Generally in messenger services, user adds or deletes contacts and let knows server about it. Server then takes necessary actions.

However, our requirement is "server decides contacts list, makes roster changes accordingly and clients receives updates about the same". How can we achieve this in Tigase?

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated API in the Tigase just for that. It is called a DynamicRoster. Maybe the name is the most accurate. Dynamic because it is managed by the server and it can change any time user requests the roster.
Anyway, there are code examples in the Tigase main code repository. You can have multiple dynamic rosters active at the same time and they can retrieve contacts from different locations.
There is also a roster protocol extension which allows you to keep extra information for the contacts in the dynamic roster such as phone numbers, etc... More info about this o the Tigase.org website in the devel guide section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Artur, thanks for this info. Gone through a related thread on tigase.org. What I gather is, Client gets roster contacts only once they logs in. There is no way for client to know changes made in roster while client is logged in. Some external mechanism has to be set to achieve this.

Comment: For the normal roster, the changes are instantly populated to DB and to all user's connections. However, for the dynamic roster it is more difficult as the change is made in 'database' or a system which is seen as a database from the Tigase server point of view. Therefore if you need to push dynamic roster changes to the user you might want to implement an admin ad-hoc command to do so.